# gij (GNU libgcj) version

Tags: java, linux, ssh

Good day to everybody!
I wrote simple program :

```
import java.lang.System;

public class hello{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

This is working fine if run it on local server. But i'm facing issue when i access this program remotely like this:

```
ssh remote_machine "java hello"
```

I'm getting below error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hello
at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:./],    parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
at gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
```

I found that it's becasue of incosistency of jvm version and code compiled java version.
Incosistency is happening because when i created and complied the code that machine is using java 1.5 , but when i remotely accessing it, it's using java 1.4 via "gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.1.2 20080704"

Question : is it possible to by pass "gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.1.2 20080704" and use initially used java version when i access it remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Source [1.6 Code Generation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcj/Code-Generation.html#Code-Generation)

> In addition to the many gcc options controlling code generation, gcj
>   has several options specific to itself.
>
> - -C
>     This option is used to tell gcj to generate bytecode (.class files) rather than object code.
>
> ...
>
> - -ftarget=VERSION
>     This can be used with -C to choose the version of bytecode emitted by gcj. The default is ‘1.5’. When not generating bytecode, this
>     option has no effect.

So you can use `-C` together with `ftarget=1.4` option to generate bytecode for version 1.4

Comment: Question was if it's possible bypass that default used jvm. Because i know how to generate bytecode for 1.4 version.Why i didn't do it is becaseu i have to fully rewrite the code , in order to it become compatible with 1.4 version.